# How to connect the translated memory to the development process

Tags: localization

I’m looking for a way to connect translation memory into the build process.

My team hires a outsourcing localization company for localization.
And uses Memsource (aka. Phrase) with team plan for the integration.
But, the Memsource cloud gets slower: it feels like we pay more than it deserves.

Is there anyone who has some advise for the better tools to manage and integrate the translation memory to the development? It doesn't have to be a SaaS, a server might response faster.

*CAT tools I used: SmartCAT, Memsource.
*Too many text keys to use Localize.